# JavaScript conditional return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a Boolean value from a simple condition like this one :

```
let object = {name: 'test'};
console.log(1 == 1 && object);
```

But this console.log doesn't displays Boolean value `true`, but the entire object `{ name: 'test' }`.
Can you explain me why ?

Why do I have to use `!!`, to return a Boolean value like this ?

```
console.log(1 == 1 && !!object);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is `object` doing here?

Comment: `Why do I have to use !!, to return a Boolean value like this ?` because that's how you "coerce" a variable to a Boolean

Comment: Its just an exemple, I just want to check if the object variable exists

Comment: Look up the `&&` operator. If both expressions are truthy, it will resolve to the last expression.

Comment: an object is always truthy though ... even `{} == true`

Comment: `console.log(object !== undefined)` ?

Comment: Okay thanks for you helps guys

Comment: in `1 == 1 && !!object` the `1 == 1` is redundant

Comment: See the duplicate. `x && y` evaluates as either `x` or `y` depending on if `x` is truthy or not. It doesn't coerce to a boolean.